# Biomass model with density

Tags: r

I am trying to develop a common biomass model for several species with wood density.

here is my data set

```
Species_Name    DBH_cm    Wood_Density      Leaf_Biomass_kg
Aam             10.9         0.55             4.495175666
Aam             8.3          0.55             3.003987585
Aam            18.3          0.55             7.0453234
Akashmoni      26.6          0.68             8.68327883
Akashmoni      18            0.68             5.514198965
Akashmoni      20.6          0.68             7.140993296
Amloki         13.7          0.64             0.418757191
Amloki         14.6          0.64             0.348964326
Amra           19            0.29             0
Arjun          13.3          0.82             0
Bajna          13            0.70             0
Bel            19.6          0.83             0.458638794
Sal            14.40         0.82             0.996750392
Sal            12.20         0.82             0.644956136
Sal            10.00         0.82             0.947928706
Sal            14.20         0.82             0.767434214
Sal            11.50         0.82             0.636970398
Sal            13.20         0.82             0.445111844
Sal            13.30         0.82             0.706039477
Sal            10.70         0.82             0.475809213
```

I tried to give NA to missing values by using

```
tree[which(tree$Leaf_Biomass_kg == 0),]$Leaf_Biomass_kg <- NA
```

my model code is

```
library(nlme)
start <- coef(lm(log(Leaf_Biomass_kg)~log(DBH_cm)+log(Wood_Density), data=tree))
start[1] <- exp(start[1])
names(start) <- c("a","b1", "b2")

m <- nlme(Leaf_Biomass_kg~a*DBH_cm^b1*Wood_Density^b2, 
                        data=cbind(tree,g="a"), 
                        fixed=a+b1+b2~1, 
                        start=start, 
                        groups=~g, 
                        weights=varPower(form=~DBH_cm))
```

it gives

> Error in finiteDiffGrad(model, data, pars) : 
>     NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Can anyone help me in this regard

I add na.action=na.exclude in my model but the problem still exists

```
m <- nlme(Leaf_Biomass_kg~a*DBH_cm^b1*Wood_Density^b2, 
                        data=cbind(tree,g="a"), 
                        fixed=a+b1+b2~1, 
                        start=start, 
                        groups=~g, 
                        weights=varPower(form=~DBH_cm)
                        na.action=na.exclude)
```

Comment: I added na.action=na.exclude in my model but it shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing values `NA` in your data set. Try setting `na.exclude` or remove records with `NA` values. You may want to impute missing values. This question has been adressed here: 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/how-does-r-handle-missing-values-in-lm